# Azure Web App Mcrypt Installation

Tags: php, laravel, azure, deployment, mcrypt

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel app using git to Azure. I already installed the following extensions to my app;

Composer 0.3.2
PHP7 x86 (Laravel)0.0.2
Php Manager 1.2.0
phpMyAdmin 4.5.3.1

However when I push my app, I get the following error;

```
> php artisan clear-compiled
remote: Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
remote: 
remote:                       
remote:   [RuntimeException]  
remote:   Error Output:       
remote:                       
remote: 
remote: install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
remote: 
remote: {"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Way\\Generators\\GeneratorsServiceProvider' not found","file":"D:\\home\\repository\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\ProviderRepository.php","line":157}}An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: 
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
To https://mburakergenc@larabook.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/larabook.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

I believe that mcrypt is not installed with the php and that causes the error. However I couldn't figure out how to install mcrypt on a windows server on Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I removed scripts part from my composer.json file and the deployment was successful. However I don't know how sufficient is this solution.